# ajax file upload image get height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I want to be able to change the height of an image uploaded using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
$("#submitimage").click(function(){
    var data = new FormData(),
        // ClientHeight is not getting the image height it is getting the height of some other element.
        height = $("#file")[0].clientHeight,
        width = $("#file")[0].clientWidth,
        FileName = $("#file").val();
    console.log(height);
    console.log(width);
    FileName = FileName.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
    data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload_file.php",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            newimage = "<br><img src='uploadedimages/"+FileName+"' width='"+width+"' height='"+height+"' alt='new image' /><br>";
            $(newimage).appendTo(".current-bulletin");
        }
    });
});
```

});

I use console.log to get the height and width it is returning and it always 22x272 so I believe clientheight is getting the file button height or something like that.

Can I get the height from there or is it better to somehow get the height of the image after it is loaded and then change it?

Answer (score 0):

So with javascript I still have not found anyway to do this, however I gave the image a class new-img and in css made it have a max-width: 100%; best I could do.